# Where do i get a list of attribute 'lang' values - what standard covers this, for SEO optimization?

Tags: html, seo, multilingual

I'm working on a [web-site](http://indiranagar.bangalore-property-buy.com/) that I need to optimize for multiple-languages. I want to provide support in 3-4 languages, *'en', 'de', 'cn'* - the trouble is, I'm **not sure what Saudi-Arabia and the gulf countries use**.

Is there **an authoritative document that lists out the mappings between nationstate => 'lang-value'** Where can i find such a document? What web-standard covers this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) says that language codes come from [RFC1766](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1766.txt), which says:

> The following registrations are predefined:
>
> In the primary language tag:
>
> - All 2-letter tags are interpreted according to ISO standard
>          639, "Code for the representation of names of languages" [ISO
>          639].
> - The value "i" is reserved for IANA-defined registrations
> - The value "x" is reserved for private use. Subtags of "x"
>          will not be registered by the IANA.
> - Other values cannot be assigned except by updating this
>          standard.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes